# How to determine number of roots of $a^k + b^k \equiv c^k \pmod{d}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Is there a way to determine number of roots of $a^k + b^k \equiv c^k \pmod d$? It is an algorithmic task, not theoretic math. I am not looking for a closed formula.

Comment: You want the set $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfying the equation or do you know any one or more of them?

Comment: @zed111, I want to get number of roots this equation for some $(k, c, d)$

Comment: If the numbers are not too large, I would construct the (array of) values $a^k\pmod{d}$. Then it's just a simple test :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithmically, I would generate the list $$1^k\pmod{d}, 2^k\pmod{d}, 3^k\pmod{d},\ldots, (d-1)^k\pmod{d}$$

Then, I would calculate the $d^2$ differences of two elements from this list, and check which of them happen to be $c^k\pmod{d}$.

There are various ways to optimize this process for speed, but they depend on which of the unknowns (if any) are large.